# Find the intervals where f is concave upwards and downwards, and inflection points (based on graph)

Tags: calculus

It's easy to find the concavity based on an equation, but for some reason I don't understand how you could figure it out just by looking at it.
I also need to find the inflection points in a certain order. What can I do to figure it out, and could you provide one example?

[image: Graph 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intuitively, there are a couple ways you could determine the concavity of a graph by looking at it:

1. If the graph is opening "up" then it's concave up. Imagine connecting the top two graphs in the image below. You should get an upward-shaped parabola. Conversely, if the graph is opening "down" then it's concave down. Connect the bottom two graphs and you should get a downward-shaped parabola.
2. You can also determine the concavity of a graph by imagining its tangent lines. If all the tangent lines are *below* the graph, then it's concave up. If all the tangent lines are above the graph, then it's concave down. If the tangent line is *on* the actual graph, then you have an inflection point (i.e. a straight line). The picture below demonstrates this.

[image]

Now let's consider your problem. From $0<x<2$ the graph is opening upwards (if we were to continue drawing this segment, it would look like an upward-shaped parabola). So the graph is concave up in the interval $0<x<2$.

From $2<x<3$ the graph is opening downwards. So the graph is concave down in the interval $2<x<3$.

For a smooth graph (do you know what this means?) an inflection point always lies between concave up and concave down segments. So one inflection point would be $x=2$ based in our inferences above.

Can you proceed in a similar manner?

Comment: Thank you so much Hadi! I was able to figure out the rest from the information you gave me. That's a lot easier than I was thinking (thank goodness).